# Cut down or take down (instead of reduce)

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

A guy is hired for a day,and his performance was not very satisfactory(even for one day). There are two employers. So one of them sats(jokingly) says:

> Let's **cut down (or take down)** his pay a bit.(let's give him lesser pay [though it was for one day])

So what should be used(of course other than the one in the circular brackets): **take down/cut down**?

Comment: Neither is idiomatic. I would say *let's reduce his pay* or *let's pay him less*.

Comment: @JasonBassford How about *let's cut his pay*?

Comment: @userr2684291 I don't think that would sound quite right for a one-day job. It would be okay if it were somebody working at a salaried job.

Answer (score 1):

[Cut down](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut%20down%20the%20pay%2C%20take%20down%20the%20pay&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20down%20the%20pay%3B%2Cc0)  is more appropriate referring to the pay.

From: [The Congressional Globe](https://books.google.it/books?id=VwScpNSkAJIC&pg=PA153&dq=%22cut%20down%20the%20pay%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV88KZwcPhAhXC2aQKHdKaAhwQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22cut%20down%20the%20pay%22&f=false):

> ....we must not ***cut down the pay of the General of the Army.*** Well, if Congress does not want ***to cut down the pay*** of the General, Congress need not do it; but I would just as soon ***cut down the pay*** of one ...

[Take down](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/take-down-something) is generally used in different contexts:

> to remove something that was previously put up or put in place:
>
> - It must be time to take down the holiday decorations.
>     take down something.

​

> to write something that you are looking at or listening to:
>
> - I can take down the messages that come in.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: That example of "cut down the pay" is from 1870. Since the 1920s, the expression of cutting someone's pay has been more common than cutting down someone's pay.      Reference: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut+the+pay%2Ccut+down+the+pay&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20the%20pay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccut%20down%20the%20pay%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"Cut his pay" would be the best terminology to use in the case of reducing ones pay.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Answer (score -1):

**take down** does not mean **to reduce something**. A proper phrasal verb for this meaning would be **cut down**

And you should say

> Let's cut down his pay.

**take down** means **to reduce sth from a higher level to a lower level**

> Take the book down from the shelf.